# Using capturing parentheses and "not in" together in a useful regex search/replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-negation

I would like to search and replace part of a number in a csv file but not include entries where the searched sting is preceded by a comma (see picture below). I want to drop "30" from each of the numbers highlighted by the green circle but not the "30" highlighted by the red circle when using replace all.

I've tried `,30[0-9](.+)` and `,30[^,](.+)` for the search string but don't know how to include the `[0-9]` or `[^,]` in the replace field. The best I could come up with for the replace term is `,$1` but that replaces the "1" in ",30102," to produce ",02," instead of what I need, ",102,".

Is there something I can add to the the replace term to include the missing character or is there a another more elegant method to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove `30` that is preceded with `,` and followed with a digit.

Use

```
,30(\d)
```

and replace with `,$1`. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C30%28%5Cd%29&i=text%2C3001234%2C30%2C30456&r=%2C%241).

The `(\d)` will capture a digit to Group 1 and `$1` will restore it in the result.

If you want to remove `30` after a comma and before any word char (to also include cases where the `30` is followed with `_`, digits or letters), use

```
,30\B
```

and replace with a mere `,`. See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C30%5CB&i=text%2C3001234%2C30%2C30456&r=%2C).